# How to extract the data from hyperlink in excel cell using python win32ComClient

Tags: python, win32com

I am beginner of python.Can u please tell me how to get the data from the link in excel sheet using `win32Com client`

I have number of rows which is having link in the excel sheet. How to get through?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import win32com.client

app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
app.visible = True

workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("MyExcel.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.Sheets[0]

print(sheet.Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address)
```

Check the complete documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837970(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: after doing this one I am gettin error like Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "i.py", line 8, in <module>
    print sh.Range("C1").Hyperlinks.Item(2).Address
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Item
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)

Comment: try printing out `print sheet.Range("C1").Hyperlinks`. You should get output as `<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library.Hyperlinks instance at 0x56127120>`?

Comment: Check [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837630%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for Hyperlinks. `Item` gets the single object from the collection.

Comment: After running the script  and print print sheet.Range("C1").Hyperlinks  i am getting the value <COMObject <unknown>>

Comment: Seems like the entry in `C1` cell is not a hyperlink.

Comment: try printing out print sheet.Range("C1").Hyperlinks. You should get output as <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library.Hyperlinks instance at 0x56127120>? ya i tried .., why this one @sk11